# How to add links on the right side of the sharepoint wiki site

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-enterprise, wiki

I am newbie to sharepoint and using sharepoint 2007 to create a wiki site. I would like to know how to add links on the right side of the page(similar to on the left side)..some thing like [this](http://cdn.tripwiremagazine.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/lepores-fabulas.jpg)

Right now my page looks like this

[image]

And one more thing, I don't have access to sharepoint designer. Is there any way to customize the page online?

**Note:** I posted the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630629/how-to-add-links-on-the-right-side-of-the-sharepoint-wiki-site) and waiting for answers..

Comment: Rule number one: only post your question once!

Comment: Your "this" link looks exactly like your page...?

Comment: @Christophe I am sorry..Did i post twice?

Comment: yes, you even said so in your question...

Comment: I edited the question, Now "this" link points to different site.. I posted the same question but on two different sites..

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to make this work without using tools like SharePoint Designer. In order to have navigation or quick launch on the right hand side of the screen you need to change either the master page or the CSS, probably both. For this, you will need SharePoint Designer.